# javascriptによるSJIS変換およびBASE64変換

Tags: javascript

画面上から取得した値(UTF-16)をSJISに変換し、ハッシュコード変換して使用。
BASE64変換を行い、再度使用(外部システムにPOST)
最終的に外部システム側で受け取った値が???になってしまいます。
SJIS変換箇所やBASE64の変換箇所でおかしいところがあればご指摘を頂きたく。

配列で変換を行う等のトライ&エラーを行ってみたのですが、どうしても正常に変換ができない状態です。
SJIS変換にはGitHubで公開されている [encoding.js](https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js) 、ハッシュ値生成にcrypt.jsを使用しています。

■該当箇所のみ抜粋

```
// 画面の設定値取得(hoge1,2は英数字、itemNameのみ全半角混合)
let hoge1 = 'hoge1';
let hoge2 = 'hoge2';
let itemName = '商品名称(にほんごめい)'

// SJIS変換(encoding.jsを外部jsとして使用)
hoge1 = Encoding.convert(hoge1 , 'SJIS');
hoge2 = Encoding.convert(hoge2 , 'SJIS');
itemName =　Encoding.convert(itemName, 'SJIS');

// SJIS変換後の全項目を連結
let result = hoge1 + hoge2 + itemName； 

// 連結後の値をハッシュ値に変換(crypto-jsを外部jsとして使用)
let spsHashcode = new CryptoJS.SHA1(result)

// 外部システムにxml形式でpostする必要があるため、作成
// 全角含む項目はBASE64変換を行い、送付する必要あり
let postData='';
postData = '<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Shift_JIS"?>';
postData += '<request id="XXXXX">';
postData+='<hoge1 >'+hoge1 +'</hoge1 >';
postData+='<hoge2 >'+hoge2 +'</hoge2 >';
postData+='<item_name>' + btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(itemName))) + '</item_name>'; 
postData += '<sps_hashcode>' + spsHashcode + '</sps_hashcode>';

(外部システムにpostDataをPOST)
```

Comment: `Encoding.convert`などという非標準クラスが突然コード内に現れていますが， https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js でしょうか

Comment: すみません、文字コード変換にあたってご指摘にあるencoding.jsを使用しております。

Comment: 期待する値と一致しないのが、SJIS変換なのか、SHA1なのか、BASE64なのか、問題を切り分けましょう。正しい値を知っているのは質問者さんだけです。

Comment: sayuriさん　デバックで確認したところSJIS変換時点で ¨¤¿Núïp  のように文字化けしてしまっているため、SJIS変換時に既に期待する値と一致していないと考えています。その後のBASE64変換では、文字化けした文字列がそのまま変換されていた(デコードすると文字化け文字列に戻せる)ため、変換自体は正常に行われているのかな？という状況です。

Comment: @ケイン池谷 JavaScriptはUTF-16専用でありそもそもSJISを扱う機能はありません。SJIS変換結果をそのまま画面出力したとしても無理やりUTF-16として表示されるだけです。その点を理解してデバッグできていますか？ ちなみにencoding.jsの開発には私もささやかながら協力しています。

Comment: unescape()は何をする関数ですか? XMLの受け取り側のコードはどうなっていますか?

Comment: @sayuri ブラウザのデバックツールで見ていましたが、ツール上の表示が文字化けしているだけということですか。SJISでちゃんとした文字列であることを確認する方法があるでしょうか？SJIS→UNICODEへの逆変換をかけて想定の文字列に戻るのは確認したのですが…

Comment: @int32_t unescape()は16進数にエンコードしてくれているようです。すいません、これをもとにしました。 https://paulownia.hatenablog.com/entry/2019/02/07/201320

Comment: @int32_t 「受け取り側のコード」ですが、外部システムのリクエストの帰り値という意味でしょうか？？向こう側のエラー体系のため、詳細がわからないのですが「属性エラー」：格納可能なデータ型以外が指定された場合に発生　が帰ってきています。

Comment: あ、失礼しました。unescape()は非推奨ですがECMAScriptで定義されている標準の関数ですね。XML受け取り側のコードはわからないということですね。

Answer (score 1):

(問題解決を確認できないので、当て推量の回答となります)

「GitHubのencoding.js」というのが https://github.com/polygonplanet/encoding.js/ これだとすると、`itemName =　Encoding.convert(itemName, 'SJIS');` の結果、`itemName` はシフトJISのバイト列を U+0000 〜 U+00FF で表現した文字列になるようです。それを

```
    btoa(unescape(encodeURIComponent(itemName)))
```

すると、`encodeURIComponent()` は `itemName` を無理やりUTF-8に再エンコードしてパーセントエンコーディングします。`unescape()` はそれを ISO-8859-1 としてパーセントデコードしています。結果、非アスキー文字は壊れます。

おそらく、

```
    btoa(itemName)
```

だけで目的の「シフトJISをBase64した文字列」になると思われます。